# where can I create Facebook application secret key?

Tags: android, facebook, secret-key

I already created facebook ID for my app and where can I get Fb application secret key for my android app?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to facebook developer page https://developers.facebook.com/

if you have an account, click on **My Applications** and then select your application.

Next you see the page with all the information of your app, the secret key is there all you to do is click in **Show**  and the Secret Key becomes visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create Facebook Application Secret Key. The Facebook automatically generate it when you add a new app. For more details check their [developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register#app-secret).

> Facebook auto-generates an app secret associated with your application. The application secret authenticates requests made by your application to Facebook servers and should be treated like a password.

Follow @fernando-payares Answer to know your **App Secret**